# JavaFx TableView Columns don't fill the TableView Width

Tags: java, xml, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a TableView generated with SceneBuilder and all the columns are FXML imports from other views, until there no problem, but the columns don't fill the width.

I tried to fix this with scene builder and FXML, but no luck, all the sizes are computed.

I tried to code it with a change listener that checks every time the window changes size to adapt the size of the columns.

This works and the columns resize to the proper width (basically I am getting the table view width and divide it by the number of columns), but for some reason the point where the column starts doesn't change and they overlap with each other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please accept the answer that works for you @OmarAlhadidy https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: In the end the answer of @Developer66 was right, but my problem was related to a css file that was messing with my columns sizes

Comment: Thanks for accepting... I hope it works now

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Select the TableView in Scenebuilder an go to the Properties an change "Colum Resize P..." to the value > "constrained-resize":

[image]

Normally thats all you need.

If that doesn't work, you can try to reset the columns values:

- Select all columns you have at the same time
- Go to Layout and change all setting to the settings in the picture
  [image]

This should work.

Comment: Using computed size makes my columns shrink to nothing and that other property doesn't exist anymore