# javafx, hieight of table is not resizing

Tags: javafx-8

I have created TableView in javafx using scenebuilder. It looks great in small window, but when I make it full screen it do not resize it's height but width only. And it also shows one extra empty column that I have not created. So please help me. I have just called fxml file of using using main.java class.

[The UI I created in SceneBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TBLh.png)

[The Window after full screen with extra unwanted column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rKUB.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFx TableView Columns don't fill the TableView Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294622/javafx-tableview-columns-dont-fill-the-tableview-width)

Comment: Thanks.... I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve those problems using bindings:

1. Column width:

   If you want to be equally divided then:

   ```
   first.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(3));
   last.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(3));
   email.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().divide(3));
   ```

   Or instead of using `divide(3)` you can set any division for example: 40% 40% 20%

   Like:

   ```
   double firstPercent = 0.4;
   double lastPercent = 0.4;
   double emailPercent = 0.2;

   // firstPercent + lastPercent + emailPercent = 1 !!!

   first.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().multiply(firstPercent));
   last.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().multiply(lastPercent));
   email.prefWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().multiply(emailPercent));
   ```
2. TableView height:

   ```
   tableView.prefHeightProperty().bind(content.heightProperty());
   ```

   where the `content` is the reference of the `VBox`